# Deploy .cspkg to Azure Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

In my build pipelines I'd like to take `.cspkg` package and use `csrun` utility to spin up the service locally in Azure Emulator and run some E2E tests against it. Is it possible to run `.cspkg` as it is or you can only do it when you have `csx` folder inside the cloud project?

Thank you.